# Why does it not go into catch when it is not applicable to the try method?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

why does the try fail and the catch doesn't go where I can click on the next page to find the fleet?

Code:

```cs
try
{
    if (!_regRep.btnNext.Displayed && !_regRep.btnNext.Enabled)
    {       
        _fleetRep.btnDelete(Fleetname).Click();
    }
}
catch
{
    if (_regRep.btnNext.Displayed && _regRep.btnNext.Enabled)
    {
        objCommon.Click(_regRep.btnNext);
        _fleetRep.btnDelete(Fleetname).Click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think, the catch is not executed. The code in the try & catch is 80% the same, so probably the code in the catch fails as well.

Comment: Presumably the code doesn't throw an exception. Did you verify that it does?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in the debugger to see where (or indeed _**if**_) exceptions are being thrown?

Comment: Please guys I am a newbie can you correct it?

Comment: @Diado yes I have debugged it and gives me : Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[text()='Delete Fleet']"}

Comment: @Butler then the issue is that it cannot identify the delete fleet button. I presume the button text is not “Delete Fleet”.

Comment: #Emcrank you are right

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved guys a lot more cleaner:

```
            try
            {
                if (_regRep.btnNext.Displayed && _regRep.btnNext.Enabled)
                {
                     objCommon.Click(_regRep.btnNext);
                    _fleetRep.btnDelete(Fleetname).Click();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _fleetRep.btnDelete(Fleetname).Click();
                Console.WriteLine("No delete found: " + ex.Message);
            }
```